# Does Madden 2010 Have Off-Season Drills

Tags: madden-10

Me and my brother are playing a franchise in Madden NFL 2010 and we just finished the season. We thought there would be drills/training during the off season, but we couldn't find anything before simulating to the next season. Am I thinking about a previous Madden game? We both thought for sure that 2010 had drills. If anyone knows if it has it or how to do them, please answer.

Comment: You should mention which platform you're playing it on. The PlayStation 2 and Wii versions may be different from the PlayStation 3 and Xbox 360 versions.

Comment: It is in the Xbox 360.